# “Play with a guitar” VS “Play on a guitar”

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idiomatic-language

If I play a song using my guitar, can I say these interchangeably?

> I play it **with** my guitar.

> I play it **on** my guitar.

Context: Let’s say I heard someone listening to a song and I am telling him/her, “I like that song. I play it on/with my guitar.” I am sure we can use “on,” I think “with” is probably okay too but I feel I am more used to the use of “on” with musical instruments so I wanted to make sure if we could use “with” as well. I think they have different connotations but I guess they are both usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the verb "play", and with the meaning of playing music, "on" necessarily indicates what is used *as the musical instrument*, so "I play it on my guitar" is the most natural, and can only mean the guitar itself is the musical instrument. Even if the song is *drummed* on the guitar, the guitar itself is the drum.

In the same context, the preposition "with" indicates *what object* you used to play the song. If you name a musical instrument, it most likely means you played it *on* that musical instrument, but it could also mean you used the guitar in some other way to play the song, like using it to push the notes on a piano, or hit a xylophone, or just beat out the rhythm on a table.

So both will be understood, but "on" is more natural.

Comment: +1 with caveat that your case of "with" being understood to play a piano "with" a guitar, etc, requires some amount of comic overthinking.

Comment: Thanks. So the two of you don’t exactly think it is unnatural to use “with” in my provided case and a native speaker could use it, but it’s still less natural than the use of “on” to some degree. Am I right?

Comment: @FireandIce Yes, that's exactly it. :)

Comment: @gotube I wonder why the other users don’t agree though.

Comment: Playing a song on the guitar is standard. However, it's best not to play with your guitar, you might damage it.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way of saying you are able to play the instrument would be:

- I play (the) guitar.

The idiomatic way of saying that a song was played using the instrument would be:

- I played [the song] **on** guitar.

"Played with a guitar" may be understood but just isn't idiomatic. In British English, "played with" is an idiomatic way of saying you handled something thoughtlessly or ignorantly. I'm a musician myself and when a musician says something like "I play *with* the guitar" (or more commonly, "I play *around with* the guitar") it is generally a way of saying that you do use the instrument but you are not fully competent at playing it, that is perhaps not your main instrument.

Comment: Thanks. But, “with” can mean “by the use of.” So you say it is not idiomatic to say “I played it on my guitar” while I am sure we can say *he chopped the woods **with** an axe,* *he ate the beans **with** a fork* etc? So we can’t just use *“with”* along with *“play”* in the meaning of *“by the use of”*? For example can’t we say *”He likes playing fighting games with a controller instead of an arcade stick”*?

Comment: The user steemic here doesn’t seem to agree with you: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/play-on-play-with.2793690/

Comment: @FireandIce Yes but that isn't idiomatic when it comes to musical instruments. Or other things, for that matter. You wouldn't say "I drove home with my car", either.

Comment: I see. Do you think we can use “play with” when talking about playing using a controller like in the example I gave. Say I saw my friend playing a game using a keyboard and a mouse, can I go up to him and say *“Oh, you’re playing with a keyboard and a mouse? I always play with a controller.”* Perhaps I need to open another topic for this.

Comment: @FireandIce It really is a case-by-case basis. Playing a video game, I would probably say 'with' a controller (or 'I'm using a controller') but its far more idiomatic to say you're playing "on" the console or gaming platform rather than the interface. On the other hand, PC gamers tend to say "I'm playing *on* keyboard" if they aren't using a controller. There would be exhaustive list of idiomatic prepositions.

Comment: This answer doesn't squarely address the question. The original user provided the exact context - i.e., using the word "my", which I thinks makes a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

*"Play it with my guitar"* is not a natural way of speaking.

Possibly because, although it would be clear what you meant from context, 'playing with', would normally mean you were, for example, cleaning, tuning, or making adjustments.

Remember, 'with' and 'on' are prepositions, and prepositions are as much chosen more according to custom than by any rule. There are various rules that have been 'back fitted' to various situations (such as when you ride on something and when you ride in it), but there is no universal rule, and you need to seek out anything applicable, or learn on a case by case basis.

In this instance, 'played it with my guitar' is just not the way native speakers say it.

Comment: Thanks. But, “with” can mean “by the use of.” So you say it is not idiomatic to say “I played it on my guitar” while I am sure we can say *he chopped the woods **with** an axe,* *he ate the beans **with** a fork* etc? So we can’t just use *“with”* along with *“play”* in the meaning of *“by the use of”*?

Comment: The user steemic here doesn’t seem to agree with you: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/play-on-play-with.2793690/

Comment: The choice of preposition is not constant for any verb. We travel **on** a train or bus, but *in* a car. Sometimes it's obvious: e.g. *"I put the roof **on** the house"*, "*I went **under** the bridge"*, but sometimes, custom trumps logic. Steemic is talking about a tablet, not a musical instrument.

Comment: I see but I can find instances on the web where “with” is used with “play” in the sense of “by the use of.” For example, do you think “He plays video games with a controller instead of a keyboard and a mouse” is a wrong sentence too? Or even if you think it is wrong, wouldn’t any native English speakers say it?

Comment: No, that sentence is not wrong. As I've tried to explain above, when using prepositions the usage is not necessarily logical and there can be variations based on both the verb and noun involved. Here 'with' is usual for the construction in question, but musical instruments are an exception.

Comment: @PRL75 Again, you're making things up. Choice of preposition is often dictated by the verb. And there are very clear rules that determine why we use *on* a bus but *in* a car. Further, that choice is not dictated by the verb at all. The fact you don't know these rules doesn't mean they don't exist, so don't say things like "the preposition choice is not constant for any verb". It's false and detrimental to the learners who come here for help, not harm.

Comment: @gotube Again, you contradict yourself in one comment. You say *"there are very clear rules that determine why we use on a bus but in a car"*, then say "Don't say: *the preposition choice is not constant for any verb"*. Please stop adding nonsensical comments to my answers. Also, why do you keep adding comments saying there are rules and not quoting or citing them? It makes it look as if you're being intentionally unhelpful.

Comment: @PRL75 I choose to spend my time here because *language learners are my people*, and it's important to me to help them improve. If someone gives an incorrect answer, I correct it. I'm sorry you don't like it, but for the sake of everyone who's going to read it in the years to come, I'm not going to leave it uncorrected. I'll dial it back as much as I can, but please help me out by also dialing back broad claims along the lines of, "*there's no rule about X*". OK?

Comment: @gotube I respect and appreciate what I have seen you do here, adding comments that enable people to improve questions and answers, and apologise for being over snippy in some of my replies. I think we are slightly askew in  that you have read some of my answers in a way I didn't intend. When I have said that there isn't a hard and fast rule, or something similar, what I have been trying to get across is that there is no single rule, or small set, that encompasses all the variation on the theme that the question asked. Trying to help in helping them avoid looking for some thing not there. ctd.

Comment: ... I need to find a form of words that says that without overstepping the mark.

Comment: @PRL75 1/3 Wow. Thanks for telling me this! I think I get what you're saying. In some parts of grammar, a single rule or a small set of rules cover the whole thing, with few to no exceptions (present simple verb forms). In other areas of grammar though, the broadest rules may not cover much (adverbs), or there may be exceptions everywhere that run deep, all the way down to the level of individual words (preposition choice; article usage). ...

Comment: ... 2/3 I think of the rules that govern down at this level as "granular" because there are so many, and each one is so tiny. English students who have learned enough to be able to ask questions on this site are mostly hunting for the granular rule that will solve the narrowly-scoped problem they have in front of them. So while they're *wishing* for *The One Rule to Rule them All (TM)*, they're expecting *and very happy to learn* the details of a rule with very limited scope. ...

Comment: ... 3/3 For instance, the choice between "on" or "in" a vehicle is governed by whether people are expected to stand up or not, respectively. Despite the tiny scope, *this is a rule of English grammar with equal standing to any other rule of English grammar.* We'd never describe the rules for the present simple verb form as "back fitted", nor determined "on a case by case basis", nor chosen "according to custom". It's the same mistake to make these claims about granular rules.

Comment: @gotube " ... are mostly hunting for the granular rule ...". I think that is the information I was missing. It make sense of your responses.